# create an append log for a detached screen session

Tags: gnu-screen, logging

I use a detached screen session to launch a process, I like it 'cause I can reattach the session and check how it is going.

The process shows output on a session, checked with `screen -r` or `screen -x`, I would like to create a log too, for this informations, both for the screen session and to a log file.

usually I use this screen command:

```
screen -A -m -d -S prog01 binarie_program
```

and I have tried this:

```
screen -A -m -d -S prog01 binario > server.log
```

with no success, in fact it creates the file called server.log but empty of rows.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From the man page:

```
 -L   tells screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows.
```

Comment: @Eddy
excellent!
best answer!
work very well...
my scrolling was too fast to see -L option from 2man"
thanx again!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Just to improve this answer, what I noticed is that the log file will be named screenlog.N where N represents the screen session. If you only have one screen session, it will be named screenlog.0 and it is placed in $HOME

Answer (score 0):

you can try utility [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script)